# Task Runner Explorer gone

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, how do I open the "Task Runner Explorer" window?

I used to have a tab at the bottom of the screen that would open it, but now the tab is gone.

[image]

Comment: Try to search it on google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open this window from the main Visual Studio menu **View - Other Windows - Task Runner Explorer**.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I found it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Google it is good, but you can also search it within Visual Studio. Press `Ctrl+Q`, type "task runner", and you'll see it.

It works for **any** window or command, which are hard to find.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the illustration. I found it, and it is working perfectly now :-)